# How to trim the text beginning when drawn the text with in the Rectangle?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

I have tried to draw the text within the rectangle using below code,

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(“1234562.021”, drawFont, drawBrush, drawRect);
```

Which has drawn below,

[image]

The right of the text has hided. But I need to hide left side of the text when the text width exceeds in rectangle like as below

[image]

Please provide any suggestions.

Thanks in Adavnce,

Comment: I'm not exceptionally familiar with `DrawString`: This only draws the text right? The rectangle was already on the screen? Can you measure the size of the text and determine if it's larger than the width of the rectangle, then pass a value for `drawRect` to "offset" where the text gets drawn?

Comment: And from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6(v=vs.110).aspx): `If the text does not fit inside the rectangle, it is truncated at the nearest word. To further manipulate how the string is drawn inside the rectangle use the DrawString overload that takes a StringFormat.`

Comment: Use the Graphics.MeasureString method to calculate the width of the text, then draw it at the correct offset from the right boundary of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start dropping chars from the beginning while the size of the current string doesn't fit into the rectangle width.

Try this:

```
        string s = "1234562.021";
        while (e.Graphics.MeasureString(s, drawFont).Width > drawRect.Width)
        {
            s = s.Substring(1);
            if (s.Length == 0)
                break;
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s, drawFont, drawBrush, drawRect);
```

It use to work for me.

Did you try to use a `StringFormater` with right alignment and passing it at the end of the `.DrawString`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the TextRenderer for drawing any text on the screen.  There are flags you can use to accomplish your alignment issue:

```
using (Pen bigPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3)) {
  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(bigPen, drawRect);
}
using (Font drawFont = new Font(SystemFonts.DefaultFont, FontStyle.Bold)) {
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "1234562.021", drawFont, drawRect,
                        Color.Black, Color.Empty,
                        TextFormatFlags.Right | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
}
```

Result:

[image]